# Need a raw xml for PropagateByExpressionRequest for MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, crm

I need a small help.

In MS Dynamics CRM there is a request - PropagateByExpressionRequest. Its purpouse to create a QuickCampaign. Here is an exmaple for C#:

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328526(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
// create the bulkoperation
PropagateByExpressionRequest request = new PropagateByExpressionRequest() {
    Activity = emailActivityEntity,
    ExecuteImmediately = false, // Default value.
    FriendlyName = "Query Based Quick Campaign",
    OwnershipOptions = ownershipOption,
    QueryExpression = query,
    Owner = new EntityReference("systemuser", _currentUser),
    PostWorkflowEvent = true,
    SendEmail = false,
    TemplateId = Guid.Empty
};
```

Thing is, we are using Java and i need a raw XML-example of this request but i could not find it.

If someone knows how it looks like or how to get it - please help. :)

**Edit 1**: CRM Version 2015.

**Edit 2**: Example (question in attributes name, format):

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <s:Body>
    <Execute>
      <request i:type="a:PropagateByExpressionRequest">
        <a:Parameters>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>FriendlyName</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:string">Query Based Quick Campaign</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>ExecuteImmediately</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:boolean">true</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>Activity</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:Entity">
              <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>activityid</b:key>
                <b:value i:type="c:string">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:value>
              </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>TemplateId</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>phonecall</a:LogicalName>
              <a:Name></a:Name>
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>OwnershipOptions</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:integer">1</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>PostWorkflowEvent</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:boolean">true</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>Owner</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>systemuserid</a:LogicalName>
              <a:Name></a:Name>
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>SendEmail</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:boolean">false</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:RequestId>
        <a:RequestName>PropagateByExpression</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: you mean fetchxml or soap request? share your java code as well

Comment: also which crm version you're using?

Comment: CRM 2015.

Java code - it is just a simple Http-Request (okHttp) with SOAP XML body. Added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP endpoint is deprecated and we have a REST web api - so we can use `PropagateByExpression` Action. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/propagatebyexpression?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Sample code will look like this: (Sorry I'm not from Java background but I know Javascript)

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.FriendlyName = "Query Based Quick Campaign";
parameters.ExecuteImmediately = false;
var activity = {};
activity.activityid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; //Delete if creating new record 
activity["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.email";
parameters.Activity = activity;
parameters.TemplateId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
parameters.OwnershipOptions = ownershipOption;
parameters.PostWorkflowEvent = true;
var owner = {};
owner.systemuserid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; //Delete if creating new record 
owner["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser";
parameters.Owner = owner;
parameters.SendEmail = false;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "https://devcrmorgname.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/PropagateByExpression", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
        } else {

        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Comment: Well, we are using CRM 2015 and if i understand correctly - Rest Api is not fully there?

Comment: @andrewGaara you’re right. Instead of solving this soap puzzle, I would put the C# code in custom workflow and execute the workflow from soap call. http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2013/03/dynamics-crm-2011-trigger-workflow-from.html

Comment: Ok. Thank for advice. I think this will be a solution.

Comment: @andrewGaara if my answer is helpful, pls upvote/accept to help community find it useful..